# makefile ifeq analog

Tags: makefile

I have really big sources with alot of different makefiles.
And now i need add one little condition there, where i can check if line contain what i want then i should use some symbols.
I know that `ifeq` must be placed at 0 column. 
But I  cant chage whole sources only for this condition.
 How i can check what conatains in variable without `ifeq`?
I have something like this in define function:

```
$(gen_cpp_objects): $(intermediates)/%.o: \
    $(intermediates)/%$(LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION) $(yacc_cpps) \
    $(proto_generated_headers)  $(my_compiler_dependencies) \
    $(LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES)
        $(transform-$(PRIVATE_HOST)cpp-to-o)
```

And i need insert condition into `$(transform-$(PRIVATE_HOST)cpp-to-o)`

i want something like this:

```
file:=somefile.someextension
define transform-cpp-to-o
@mkdir -p $(dir $@)
@echo "target $(PRIVATE_ARM_MODE) C++: $(PRIVATE_MODULE) <= $<"
ifeq ($(strip $<),$(file))
#Do something here
endif
$(hide) $(PRIVATE_CXX) \
        $(addprefix -I , $(PRIVATE_C_INCLUDES)) \
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `if` function as an inline condition:

```
$(if $(filter $(strip $<),$(file)), then-block, else-block)
```

Comment: how can i use it with variables? I mean can i change then-block to something like `test:=testvar`

Comment: You can't assign variables in then-block or else-block. Think of it more as the `?:` operator in C. However, you can assign the whole `$(if ...)` expression to a variable. If you use `=` instead of `:=`, the variable is stored in unexpanded form, and the conditional expression will be evaluated every time the variable is used.

Comment: but how ti assigns something to variable in this condition, i mean how to assign something after some condition without ifeq

Comment: You can't do that. If you need some variable to be assigned one or another way depending on a condition, you should assign that variable a conditional expression which chooses between the two alternatives.

Comment: i mean i want something like this (pseudocode) 
    if (a=="23") then
        b="good solution"
    else
        b="bad solution"